# Retrieve time from 0.pool.ntp.org in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest

How would you retrieve the current time from `0.pool.ntp.org` and convert it to a usable date in `iOS 7`?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? The return would match `[NSDate date]`
.

Comment: Wouldn't that be returning the current date from the time on your phone?  Or does that contact a time server?

Comment: @wumm Both these comments assume the phone has the right time and perhaps the OP wants to verify externally for some reason (i.e end of a trial period or soemthing).

Comment: Right, I am wanting to check an external time so that the user may not manipulate the time.

Comment: Okay, probably I commented to fast. Of course `[NSDate date]` would return the time on the phone. But by the default this time is synced with a time server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use this library: https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp
Then you can retrieve the time from the server using:

```
[NSDate networkDate];
```